# Convert STL object to VTK geometry in python

Tags: python, boolean, vtk

I am wanting to do Boolean operations on STL files with geometric primitives from the VTK library.

My problem is converting the STL geometry to something that the VTK Boolean objects will except.

I tried the following...

```
import vtk

filename = 'gyroid.stl' 
reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
reader.SetFileName(filename)
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
gyroid = vtk.vtkActor()
gyroid.SetMapper(mapper)

sphere = vtk.vtkSphere()
sphere.SetRadius(30)
sphere.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)

boolean = vtk.vtkImplicitBoolean()
boolean.SetOperationTypeToIntersection()
boolean.AddFunction(gyroid)
boolean.AddFunction(sphere)
```

But get the following error...

```
File "D:\Python codes\VTK\untitled8.py", line 29, in <module>
    boolean.AddFunction(gyroid)

TypeError: AddFunction argument %Id: %V
```

It throws the same error if I replace `gyroid` with `mapper`

How do I convert the STL mesh into something useable by VTK? Or cant I do this & need to look elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about converting STL in VTK but about how to use VTK API :)

`vtkImplicitBoolean` works on  implicits function, i.e. classes that can generate data, such as the vtkSphere. See here for [doc](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImplicitBoolean.html)
and here for [usage](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/ImplicitFunctions/BooleanOperationImplicitFunctions/)

As you have a loaded dataset, you cannot use this. Instead, use `vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter` and generate a sphere with the `vtkSphereSource`. [Here](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter.html) and [here](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/PolyData/BooleanOperationPolyDataFilter/)
for examples.

**Example**

```
sphere = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
booleanOperation = vtk.vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter()
booleanOperation.SetOperationToIntersection()
booleanOperation.SetInputConnection(0, reader.GetOutputPort())
booleanOperation.SetInputConnection(1, sphere.GetOutputPort())
```

Comment: this works but only if the cropping sphere's radius = 30, all other values lead to an empty set

Comment: in fact none of the BooleanOperators are working properly!

Comment: After some investigation, it is not the better part of VTK ... [A VTK forum post](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/adding-roemers-boolean-filter-as-a-remote-module/1635)  about using [this repo](https://github.com/zippy84/vtkbool) in VTK.

Comment: Thanks Nico I have opened up a new question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129906/vtk-boolean-operations-on-poly-data-producing-empty-sets)

Answer (score 2):

Code to convert from .stl to .vtk format. Install vtk for this using pip install vtk.

```
import sys
import vtk

# Read the .stl file
filename = sys.argv[1] 
a = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
a.SetFileName(filename)
a.Update()
a = a.GetOutput()

# Write the .vtk file
filename = filename.replace('.stl', '.vtk')
b = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
b.SetFileName(filename)
b.SetInputData(a)
b.Update()
```